# Netbeans codename one change where builds are sent

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I have created an account in Codename one, which had the free packet from my personal email.
Eventually, the company that I work at purchased the Basic subscription packet. However, the builds are still sent to my old account email, every time I press Send Android build.
How do i change where builds are sent, in order for them to be sent to the new account with the basic packet? I had an issue with space over 1200 kb.

Comment: If you open the "Codename One Preferences" window, under the "Login" icon it's written: «Important: This doesn't change the account to which builds are sent, in order to prevent abuse». I suppose that this is the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is there to prevent abuse where developers would switch accounts to circumvent the quota restrictions which goes against the terms of service. The workaround isn't intuitive to avoid such abuse:

- Reset the password in the old account
- Send a build - this build will fail
- Send a build again - it will now prompt you for an email/password

Comment: Hi, I did change my password, but from eclipse when I send my build are sending to out old user account, I need to change to our new codenameone account. If we do loging from eclipse we appers in the correct account, but the builds are sending to the old.

Comment: In Codename One Settings update to the latest. This approach no longer works in the new Codename One. Your only option is to open regedit and delete all usage of codeame1 and codenameone. We'll try to create a better way in the future

Comment: works for me deleting all inputs in regedit.